# Array find gives error "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'unknown' " doing a firebase join in Angular (Error TS2339)

Tags: arrays, angular, firebase, join, find

Hello Im trying to do this tutorial of how to make a join in firebase with angular: https://medium.com/@joaqcid/how-to-inner-join-data-from-multiple-collections-on-angular-firebase-bfd04f6b36b7

my othercomponent.ts ngOnInit:

```
this.joined$ = this.afs.collection<ChatInterface>('chats').valueChanges()
     .pipe(
       switchMap(blogPosts => {
         const authorIds = uniq(blogPosts.map(bp => bp.uid))

         return combineLatest(
           of(blogPosts),
           combineLatest(
             authorIds.map(uid =>
               this.afs.collection<User>('users', ref => ref.where('uid', '==', uid)).valueChanges().pipe(
                 map(authors => authors[0])
               )
             )
           )
         )
       }),
       map(([blogPosts, authors]) => {

    return blogPosts.map(blogPost => {
           return {
             ...blogPost,
             author: authors.find(a => a.id === blogPost.uid)
           }
         })
       })
     )
```

Its looks like easy to follow but I don't know I could do wrong (angular 8 and tutorial is 7 maybe changed the find?) but I get  error TS2339: Property 'id' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
on line: `author: authors.find(a => a.id === blogPost.uid)`

Tutorials stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-firebase-join-data?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

My chat interface:

```
 export interface ChatInterface {
  groupId: string;
  uid: string;
  content: string;
  file: string;
  date: number;
}
```

My user interface:

```
 export interface User {
  uid: string;
  email: string;
  displayName: string;
  photoURL: string;
  emailVerified: boolean;
}
```

Only difference I could find with vs code are this one Its detected as any instead of string:
This is stackblitz: [image]

This is my code: 
[image]

and authors is detected as unknown instead of User

[image]

[image]

Comment: what version of typescript are you using?

Comment: using typescript 3.5.3

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and defining the "a" as any was the solution for me :

```js
author: authors.find((a:any) => a.id === blogPost.uid)
```